# Regarding catching exception in java

Tags: java, exception

I have developed a java code that reads java files from the folder chosen by the user. It displays how many lines of code are in each file, it reads only .java filesonly and final outcome is shown on console , but I was thinking of a situation let's  say I have a folder in which there is no files at all or there is a folder in which no .java files are there in such cases I want to show a customized message by catching the exception and displaying the message there is no .java file inside the folder, please advise how to achieve that ..below is my piece of code..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {      Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
             File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); 
             int totalLineCount = 0;
             File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
                  @Override
                  public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
                      if(name.endsWith(".java"))
                      return true;
                    else
                      return false;              
                  }
                }
   );
              for (File file : files)
            {
                if (file.isFile())
                {    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                    int lineCount = 0;
                     try
                    { for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++) ;
                          } catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                    {   result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                    totalLineCount += lineCount;  
                                    }


                } }
              System.out.println("*****************************************");
              System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
              System.out.println("*****************************************");

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet())
            {   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>"+"\t"+result.size()); 
            System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>"+"\t"+ totalLineCount);

             }     

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use exceptions, the array files has the files in it, all you need is a conditional statement that checks its size.

```
if(files.length == 0) {
    //Do whatever you like to inform the user there are no java files in the directory.
}
```